# How to prevent devs subverting code coverage with useless asserts?

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

I've been looking through dev code and found some instances of devs writing tests which help to pass code coverage but which add no real value e.g.:-

```
  @Test
  public void testProcess() {
    createInvestorResponseTransformer.process(exchange);
    Assert.assertNotNull("The exchange object should not be NULL.", exchange);

  }
```

Invariably assertNotNull is used in some way.

We already have code reviews and this didn't get picked up. Other than educating the devs on writing better unit tests and the value of them, what can I do to improve the situation?

There'll always be a way of gaming/subverting the system but can I prevent the majority of them in some way with SonarQube?

Comment: "We already have code reviews and this didn't get picked up" Explicitly check for them in code reviews.

Comment: Hang on a sec. Why are you measuring coverage of the *tests*? What does that show?

Comment: To me this sounds like you have 2 problems. One is organisational - if you push some metrics which developers must achieve, they **will** find a way to game it. The other one is technical - yes, these kind of unit tests are worse than useless, they're actually harmful because they provide false sense of security. I think the solution is to educate devs on value which good unit tests provide and to actively teach them how to write them and how to recognise bad/useless ones during code reviews.

Answer (score 0):

**Full code coverage is not always nice.**

Tested code is a *huge* advantage, against regression bugs already before the first release.

However doing code coverage too early, slows down the development impetus, and means rewriting tests as code is redesigned during development.

And then often enough a test is more or less senseless.

Or it is difficult when the code is written without the correct interception points, possible hooks. *That at least should require a refactoring.*

So there is enough temptation and self-justification to disarm code coverage, at least "for the moment."

Before blaming:
- full code coverage is not the ideal code coverage: senseless, too costly in both delivered code quality and development speed

Solution:
- everything below 15% code coverage should actually not count as negative

This solution is would need a new SonarQube. Or realize that SonarQube is imperfect.

One should realize SonarQube is not always the best judge.

It will prefer:

```
A[] a = list.toArray(new A[list.size()]);
```

to

```
A[] a = list.toArray(new A[0]);
```

Strangely enough the second solution is better (faster), i.a. as the list-to-array uses a different, faster byte code level implementation.

---

***Of course one should prevent such subversion***

- Continuous reviewing also of the unit tests; what you did. Make tickets. The price to pay.
- Either let repair the unit test case, or add a comment for not testing this function.
- Manually unmark sonar-qube's warnings when a comment is present
- Instead of a comment, @SuppressWarnings might be possible; no idea